# Error sending a single delete in movilizer

Tags: movilizer

I'm sending a delete operation to Movilizer with only a key and the pool but it gives me this error:

Cannot delete primary group (Do not set group in delete command to delete entire entry)

Why?

Comment: Please, can you add the piece of code related to this message? The movilizer request could be fine

Answer (score 0):

It was because I wasn't updating my ACK. This error ocurred before and I was getting it because of the ACK. Thanks.